# Code <i> showing in wordpress post titles around website

Tags: theme-development

Some of the posts on my wordpress site have the `<i>`in them. I've just switched themes and in the new theme this code shows up all over the site wherever the title is. Related post area, front page, blog page, etc.

Is there a way to make the title render this properly?

Comment: See related for filtering the_title: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038333/wordpress-why-wont-the-title-filter-change-the-post-title

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way is to add some custom css

```
i {font-style:italic; }
```

If needed, you could add the 'important':

```
i {font-style:italic !important; }
```

If your theme supports 'extra/custom css', put that in there. Or, create a child theme and put it in that child theme's style.css .

Not recommended to put it in the theme's style.css file, as a theme update would overwrite your change.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question, when in the title, `<i>` will be just a text, not an html element, and you will not be able to style it.

Comment: If you look at the post's raw html, do you see the '<i>' code? Is there a matching '</i>' code? Does the text right after the '<i>' code look italic? Your question didn't really make it clear that there was a single '<i>' code without a closing code, so I assumed that was the case. Edit your question to make things more clear. Include a sample of the text.x